# Amazon Quicksight Time intelligence functions

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

This is my first time using amazon quicksight and I am having trouble creating a calculated measure that brings in sales from the year before the one I am evaluating in each row.

Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knB56.png]

I am looking for the simile to the function CALCULATE (SUM (SALES), PREVIOUSYEAR ()) of PowerBi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is not a complete solution but hopefully it will put you in the right direction.

I started with the following dataset:
[image]

In Quicksight, I prepared my data by calculating the Year and Month fields from the Date field of my dataset. I then defined the following calculated field:

> lag(sum(SALES), [Month ASC], 1)

I was then able to get the following result:
[image]

As mentioned, this is a partial answer as it doesn't work for May 2019 (it should be null/empty instead of 19). It might be easier to work with dates field rather than Month/Year string fields the way I did. I hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Thanks Frank S, it is rare that a tool like aws quicksight does not have more practical methods for calculations as common as this, I miss the simplicity of power bi for these cases :(

Greetings and thanks